# Debugging a linux daemon process written in C

Tags: c, linux

On occasion a daemon I wrote in C gets these error messages:

```
[Fri Dec 30 07:58:54 2016] listend[13944]: segfault at 0 ip b7601e22 sp bf901d00 error 4 in libc-2.19.so[b7575000+1a7000]

[Fri Dec 30 07:58:54 2016] listend[13948]: segfault at 0 ip b7601e22 sp bf901d00 error 4 in libc-2.19.so[b7575000+1a7000]

[Fri Dec 30 07:58:54 2016] listend[13949]: segfault at 0 ip b7601e22 sp bf901d00 error 4 in libc-2.19.so[b7575000+1a7000]

[Fri Dec 30 07:58:54 2016] listend[13950]: segfault at 0 ip b7601e22 sp bf901d00 error 4 in libc-2.19.so[b7575000+1a7000]

[Fri Dec 30 07:58:54 2016] listend[13951]: segfault at 0 ip b7601e22 sp bf901d00 error 4 in libc-2.19.so[b7575000+1a7000]

[Fri Dec 30 07:58:54 2016] listend[13952]: segfault at 0 ip b7601e22 sp bf901d00 error 4 in libc-2.19.so[b7575000+1a7000]

[Fri Dec 30 07:58:54 2016] listend[13953]: segfault at 0 ip b7601e22 sp bf901d00 error 4 in libc-2.19.so[b7575000+1a7000]

[Fri Dec 30 07:58:54 2016] listend[13954]: segfault at 0 ip b7601e22 sp bf901d00 error 4 in libc-2.19.so[b7575000+1a7000]

[Fri Dec 30 07:58:54 2016] listend[13955]: segfault at 0 ip b7601e22 sp bf901d00 error 4 in libc-2.19.so[b7575000+1a7000]
```

My question is how can I examine that address in libc-2.19.so to see which function is being called when the error occurs? I tried using gdb

but I get :

```
$ gdb code/listen/i686-Linux/listend 
.
.
(gdb) info addr 0xb7575000
No symbol "0xb7575000" in current context.
(gdb) info addr 0xb771c000
No symbol "0xb771c000" in current context.
```

Comment: Run your daemon under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org).  The bug is almost certainly not in libc; valgrind will reveal the point in _your code_ that triggered the _first_ invalid memory access.  This may not be the root cause of the bug but it is usually much closer to the root cause than what you have now.

Comment: Right, I thought if I could find which function in libc that address pointed at I could trace it back into my code.  I know 100% my code has the bug, not libc ;-)

Comment: It also helps to compile your code without optimizations and with debug symbols: `gcc -O0 -g ...`. This will improve the output of both gdb and valgrind.

Comment: Yep gcc -Wall -ggdb is what I build with.

Comment: could you just attach to the daemon with gdb and wait for it to crash?  or can you load the crash dump into gdb? and look at the call stack?

Comment: Yes, that's the next step I'm going to attempt to reproduce the traffic that crashes the daemon and watch it in gdb/valgrind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data you provide there's very little that can be done here to make a diagnose on your problem.  What I can infer is that the address, being 0, points to a `NULL` dereference in your code (you pass `NULL` as the pointer to a string address, or something similar, that makes your `printf()` call to fail --- or similar, again)  The address `0x1a7000` is where, in libc has been raised the exception.  You probably can guess the function name, by executing `nm(1)` to your libc.so.xx.xx.xx.  Dumping a core (by setting ulimit -c unlimited before executing your daemon) will allow to use the postmortem debugger.  Or perhaps the source code of the daemon would help also.  Sorry but your question is far from complete to be able to help.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for: You probably can guess the function name, by executing nm(1) to your libc.so.xx.xx.xx.  Thanks!

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, just mark it as such! :))  You'll get the actual answer with a post mortem core image and the gdb debugger also.

Comment: It throws this error intermittently, I've been monitoring for days sometimes weeks trying to catch it.

Comment: Just prepare the environment to make the process to dump a core file.  You'll get the last failure in the last core file, you don't need much more to debug the place of failure, it will probably be always the same.  And the executions not failing will not dump a core.

Comment: I've set ulimit -c unlimited a while back, but I haven't seen a core file yet.